# Command Not Found for Addon in G1ANT Studio

Tags: g1ant

So I was able to create an addon using the Selenium drivers and packages. However, even after successful loading of the addon in the Studio, when I try to run my command, I am getting an error mentioning that the command was not found.
Here's the error Image:

[image: error image]

The command is clearly showing in the addon information window, however when I try running it I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the name of your command in visual studio,  try to write it in small letters.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the suggestion, it is working now!